# this.setState does not trigger re-render in component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've got a component containing a 'logout' button, which deletes some variables from localStorage, then updates component state. It doesn't seem to trigger a render after updating the state.

I use the state to render either the logout button or a `<Redirect/>` component from react-router.

I've put my method on the onClick event of the button, and used `.bind(this)` to preserve context.

The component doesn't seem to re-render when I change state, even when I call `this.forceUpdate()` from the `setState` callback.

Is there anything I might have done wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {NavLink, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import ProtectedRoute from "../hoc/ProtectedRoute";
import Explain from "./Explain";
import User from "../util/User";
import Environment from "./Environment.js";

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {loggedIn: true};
    }

    logout(){
        User.erase();
        this.setState({loggedIn: false}, () => {
            console.log("is logged in true? ", this.state.loggedIn === true);
            this.forceUpdate(() => { console.log("forcupdate complete") });
        });
    }

    render(){
        return <div className="authenticated">
            <nav className="navigation-bar">
                <div className="nav-grp">
                    <NavLink activeClassName="active" to="/home/explain">Explain</NavLink>
                    <NavLink activeClassName="active" to="/home/environment">Environment</NavLink>
                </div>
                <div>
                    { this.state.loggedIn === true ? "In" : "Out" }
                    { this.state.loggedIn === true
                        ? <a onClick={this.logout.bind(this)}>Logout</a>
                        : <Redirect from="/home" to="/register"/>
                    }
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div className="view container">
                <ProtectedRoute path={["/home/explain/:explain","/home/explain"]} authorized={User.registered()} component={Explain}/>
                <ProtectedRoute path="/home/environment" authorized={User.registered()} component={Environment}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}

export default Home;
```

From the above, I would expect upon entering this component to see 'in' and a logout button. Upon clicking it, I would expect to be redirected back to my component at `/register` url. 
Instead, it doesn't look like any render is occurring, as I continue to see the logout button and am not redirected anywhere.

You can see above I have put `console.log`s in both the `setState` and `forceUpdate` callbacks. For the record, the 'is logged in true?' message prints, but the 'forceUpdate complete' message does not print.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: it's not the best place to bind your logout function in the render method, why not render it in the class constructor?

Comment: any errors in the console ?

Comment: There was a 'href attriubte required' error. fixed that by replacing the a with a button, but have the same result. Icepickle, not sure what you're suggesting, create a member variable to hold the JSX in the constructor? could you point me to an example?

Comment: I removed other functions and replaced Redirect to a tag and tested it. It worked well. Can you test it without User.erase()  ?

Comment: Sorry all, I've broken it myself, had a redirect loop. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

This is on me. The component we redirect to `/register` appears to be redirecting us back to `/home`, which is the component above. I'm going to refactor how user sessions are handled so I don't have this issue.

Sorry stackoverflow!

If anyone has a similar issue, roughly what's happening is: 
Register form submits, we store user token in localStorage and in register component state. Then we redirect to /home.

Clicking logout in Home component, we remove token from localStorage and redirect to /register.

register contains the user token in it's state, from the first time we visited it, and thinks registration is complete, so redirects us back to home. I'm thinking just removing user data from component state and have static functions to access user data.